# StreamWriter.WriteLine not writing in new line

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I am using the following code to write a DataTable to text file.

```
Using sbData As New StreamWriter(fileName, False, Encoding.UTF32)
    sbData.Write(String.Join("\t", dataTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().Select(Function(arg) arg.ColumnName.Trim())))
    sbData.WriteLine()
    For Each dataRow As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        sbData.Write(String.Join("\t", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(Function(arg) arg.ToString().Trim())))
        sbData.WriteLine()
    Next
    sbData.Flush()
    sbData.Close()
End Using
```

Data is getting written to the text file but neither \t (tab) is working nor WriteLine.
Instead of tab I am getting "\ t" in the text file and everything is in continuation.
Any one having any idea whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`"\t"` only works in the curly brace languages, like C#, you have to use vbTab in VB.NET.

Using utf32 is just plain weird and the reason that WriteLine() doesn't seem to work. Whatever program you use to look at the file does not expect it and will guess at the wrong encoding.  Also the reason you saw a space in "\ t".  Writing a BOM is not optional when you use unusual encodings. Do strongly consider using Encoding.UTF8 instead, the default for StreamWriter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using Notepad for reading txt files. Also my application outputs some Swedish and German chars. I don't know if they are available in UTF8. May b u can put some light on that aswell. Thanks again...

Comment: UTF8 encodes Unicode, it knows Swedish and German.  Pass `New Encoding.UTF8(True)` to ensure that Notepad will always get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: 
For tab I used ControlChars.Tab and it works perfectly.
For WriteLine I guess it has something to do with Encoding. I switched from UTF32 to Unicode and it started working.

Will try to find what exactly was the issue but for now problem is solved :-)